# Apache Beam in Python- can we write a file footer

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When we write a file in Apache Beam there is a provision to write a file header using the header parameter of the following class

`class apache_beam.io.textio.WriteToText(file_path_prefix, file_name_suffix='', append_trailing_newlines=True, num_shards=0, shard_name_template=None, coder=ToStringCoder, compression_type='auto', header=None)`

While there is no out of the box for the footer, can someone give a technique by which a footer can be added to the file that is written?

The expected output is

```
Header
Row 1
Row 2
..
..
Row 1000000
Footer
```

Comment: Have you looked at [apache_beam.io.filebasedsink](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.6.0/apache_beam.io.filebasedsink.html?highlight=footer#module-apache_beam.io.filebasedsink) module? The documentation states that you might have to adjust `open()` and/or `close()`  functions to customize the file handling or write headers/footers.

Comment: @Peter The solution worked and the implementation is indicated in the answer below. We need to override a Sink and point to the sink in a custom writer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. We need to do it by extending 2 classes

extend _TextSink and over-ride the `close()` method.

```
    def close(self, file_handle):
    if self._footer is not None:
        self.write_record(file_handle, self._footer)
    file_handle.close()
```

extend the `PTransform` class to write your own writer

```
class MyWriteToText(PTransform):
def __init__(
        self, file_path_prefix, file_name_suffix='', append_trailing_newlines=True,
        num_shards=0, shard_name_template=None, coder=coders.ToStringCoder(),
        compression_type=CompressionTypes.AUTO, header=None, footer=None):
    self._sink = _TheExtendedSink(
        file_path_prefix, file_name_suffix, append_trailing_newlines,
        num_shards, shard_name_template, coder=coders.ToStringCoder(),
        compression_type=compression_type, header=header, footer=footer)

def expand(self, pcoll):
    return pcoll | Write(self._sink)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is currently supported by Beam Java SDK but not Beam Python SDK.

As a workaround you can consider appending the footer to all files written by using a subsequent `ParDO` (`WriteToText` returns a `PCollection` with all files written).

Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-10938 for tracking.